# ("Failed to load the model due to bad model data. tags: ['serve']\nNo op named HashTableV2 in defined operations.", 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-prediction

I'm using GCP with GCS and GCMLE APIs to train my model and to predict on the cloud. I'm working on  the census dataset. And the goal is to predict a profile's income.
this is the github link of codes and scripts https://github.com/SofiaAmel/censusTest
Actually I am discovering this tool, I'm struggling with prediction, I'm testing with one profile as .json input  , the job preiction runs succussfully, but it occurs this error ***

> ("Failed to load the model due to bad model data. tags: ['serve']\nNo
>   op named HashTableV2 in defined operations.", 1)

---

ps : I'm using TF version 1.4 , if you can help don't hesitate !
Thanks in advance

Comment: how are you deploying the model? gcloud? Cloud console?

Comment: @rhaertel80 with gcloud

Answer (score 1):

This error message indicates that you have chosen a lower version of TensorFlow for serving the model than you used to train the model and the HashTableV2 op was introduced in a later version.

To fix this, be sure to specify the correct runtime version when deploying the model, e.g.,

`gcloud ml-engine version create ${VERSION} --model ${MODEL} --runtime-version=1.4`

At this time, it is not possible to specify the runtime version when using Cloud Console. We hope to add the feature shortly.

Comment: actually I specified the runtime version                                            `gcloud ml-engine versions create model_version_25 --model model_25 --origin gs://bucket-25/training/export/census/1524737041 --runtime-version 1.4`

Comment: and I just tried with 1.6 , and still the same error

Comment: @SofiaAmel our apologies for the trouble. Can you contact cloudml-feedback@google.com; send a link to the stackoverflow question and your project id + model name. In the same email, please indicate whether we have your explicit permission to look at your logs to help debug.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH  , you made my day ! I hope  that the solution for this issue will show up asap :)